# Chaining multiple Java Optionals

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

```
private void validatePGTimingRestrictions(
        Listing listing,
        ListingAutoVerificationResponse listingAutoVerificationResponse) {
    if (Optional.ofNullable(listing.getLastEntryTime()).isPresent()
            && Optional.ofNullable(listing.getTimingRestrictions()).isPresent()
            && !listing.getTimingRestrictions()) {
        listingAutoVerificationResponse.getRejectReasons()
                .add(ListingAutoVerificationErrorMessages.PG_LISTING_TIMING_ERROR);
    }
}
```

How do I optimise this code with chaining optionals and orElseGet.
listing.getTimingRestrictions() returns Boolean, listing.getLastEntryTime() returns String & add method from List returns Boolean as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **map** the `Optional` **to a completely different value**, allowing you to chain null-checks:

```
Object a, b, c;
....
Optional.ofNullable(a) // null-check for 'a'
    .map(x -> b) // null-check for 'b'
    .map(x -> c) // null-check for 'c'
    .ifPresent(x -> ...) // do something with a,b,c
```

In your case:

```
Optional.ofNullable(listing.getLastEntryTime())
    .map(x -> listing.getTimingRestrictions())
    .filter(x -> !x)
    .ifPresent(x -> ... ); // do something with the listing
```

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use Optional there?

```
if (listing.getLastEntryTime() != null && !listing.getTimingRestrictions()) {
listingAutoVerificationResponse.getRejectReasons()
           .add(ListingAutoVerificationErrorMessages.PG_LISTING_TIMING_ERROR);
}
```

would do the trick, as `getTimingRestrictions` is boolean and is a primitive type it shouldn't be `null` anyway.

Comment: Its Boolean...not boolean

Answer (score 2):

If I got everything right... :

```
if(listing.getLastEntryTime() != null){
    Optional.ofNullable(listing.getTimingRestrictions())
            .filter(x -> !x)
            .ifPresent(x -> <do whatever you want with x here>)
}
```